# Ruby: How to select and copy a portion of string within an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

Forgive me, I'm new!

I'm trying to select and copy a portion of a string from within an array; specifically, someone's last name.

```
array = ["Buffy Summers", "Willow Rosenberg", "Xander Harris", "Cordelia Chase", "Rupert Giles"]
```

I need to isolate and copy "Summers", "Rosenberg", "Harris", "Chase", and "Giles". Basically, I want to select everything after the space character through the end of the string.

I've seen this example:

```
"truncate".gsub(/a.*/, '')
=> "trunc"
```

but this selects everything before the "a", while I need to select everything after a space character. Also, this is not within an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These piece of code will do the trick:

```
surnames = array.map { |item| item.split(' ').last }
```

Comment: Yes, unless you're sure, that global vairiable `$;` has it's default value.
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split

Answer (score -1):

Implementing something similar to your suggestion, we have:

```
array.map { |s| s.gsub(/\w+\s+/,'') }                                       
#=> ["Summers", "Rosenberg", "Harris", "Chase", "Giles"]
```

or

```
array.map {|s| s.match(/\w+\z/).to_s }
#=> ["Summers", "Rosenberg", "Harris", "Chase", "Giles"]
```